# Retrieved data from JSON file shown in app, but not in Unity Editor

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So in my game, I am retrieving some data, such as characters' names, from a JSON file. If I want to change, for example, a character's name, I'll replace the values in the JSON file. The result is perfectly fine when I build an apk and run it on a phone. However, in the unity editor, neither the old nor the new value are shown and there is nothing there. I have already cleared the playerprefs and the cache, but to no avail. What should I do?

Comment: Might be easier to debug if you give a portion of your code that is retrieving information from the JSON file. Are you using any platform dependent compilation directives? Such as #if UNITY_ANDROID?

Comment: Code is required!